# Derive specific bitstream with few given information

Tags: algorithm, bitmap, binary, bit-manipulation, bit

I have a question about algorithm design.

Suppose I have **S**, **R**, and **B** these three bitstreams as below in an encoder, and the output is D.
My question is how to derive the **S** or **B** in decoder with the only given **D** and **R**.

My initial idea goes below with xor (^) operation, and **D=1001**.

```
Encoder:
S      |R      |X=S^R  |B      |D=X^B
0001   |1010   |1011   |0010   |1001
```

Moreover, in decoder, it receives only **D** and **R** as below,

```
Decoder:
D      |R      |
1001   |1010   |
```

yet basically **X=S^R** and **X=B^D**, thus **S^R=B^D** or said **D^R = S^B**. Hence, I have no idea about how to derive **S** and **B** separately.
Does any one can give an concept, or a thought, or an algorithm you known to deal with this.
Many thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. `D = S ^ B ^ R`, given D and R, you can get `S ^ B` back (as you showed), but the rest of the information is just gone.

Of course it had to be gone: you have only 8 bits, you can't store 12 bits of information in there. If you could, you could recursively apply that transformation until you've compressed any arbitrary amount of information down to a single byte.

But, maybe you have some a-priory knowledge about S and B, or some useful relation between them or between one of them and R. If you have enough of that knowledge, you might be able to reconstruct S and B (for example, if B = R, then D = S so you know them all).

Comment: R is a constant on both sides, so the OP is trying to store 8 bits with only 4 bits of space.

Comment: @ShawnC ok, I interpreted it as an other variable. Doesn't really matter though, it still can't work and the reason is the same.

Comment: How about I use a currently unknown method instead of the xor, and the decoder gets its output and R in decoder? Or eventually it's a theoretically impossible problem no matter which method I utilize.

Comment: @user3030046 there are reversible mappings from 3 things to 2, but they give 2 slightly larger things so that the total information content remains unchanged. If you try to represent 12 bits with 8 (or 8 with 4, or in general, n with m where m < n), then the pigeonhole principle will ensure that information is lost.